# Why can't ros_pcl detect my pcl headers when building?

Tags: ros, pcl, build, catkin-make-isolated, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using raspberry pi and building pcl_ros from source.

I already downloaded, built and installed pcl. I believe it is installed, since there are cmake files in `/usr/local/share/pcl-1.7`

When I run the command:

```
sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --pkg pcl_ros --install-space /opt/ros/indigo
```

I get the following error message:

```
/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/src/pcl_ros/surface/convex_hull.cpp:40:37: fatal error: pcl/surface/convex_hull.h: No such file or directory
CMakeFiles/pcl_ros_features.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/pcl_ros_features.dir/src/pcl_ros/features/feature.cpp.o' failed
```

I also know that `~/pcl-pcl-1.7.2/ surface/include/pcl/surface/convex_hull.h` exists.

I followed [these instructions](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/compiling_pcl_posix.php) when building pcl from source.

Anyone know what might cause this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222838/why-can%27t-ros_pcl-detect-my-pcl-headers-when-building?/) by [Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/22737/sebastian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 363 on 2015-12-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2015-12-21**:
You probably have not fully built pcl because of some missing dependencies. Check if surface/convex_hull.h exist in /usr/local/include/pcl-1.7/pcl. Can you paste the output of the "cmake .." call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just copied the missing .h file from `~/pcl-pcl-1.7.2/` to `/usr/local/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/surface/convex_hull.h`

Apparently just one file was not installed. Might be a mistake in the pcl source. Not sure what else might have caused it.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/22737/sebastian/) with karma: 363 on 2015-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2016-01-10**:
Nice! You should open a ticket in PCL (https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl)